# Read If-Modified-Since header in PHP CGI

Tags: php, apache, apache2, if-modified-since, suphp

My PHP script depends on being able to read the value of the `If-Modified-Since` header (yes, I know how to do this).

It worked correctly when I used PHP as mod_php, but now that I've switched to suPHP (CGI), it appears Apache itself handles requests that contain this header, without forwarding them to PHP at all.

This is silly, because Apache can't possibly know when my dynamically generated CSS file (that is what my script makes) is changed. How can I discipline Apache in this regard?

Comment: You need to tell us more about the headers you sending.  Most likely mod_cache is caching your response for you because you are sending headers that say it can.

Answer (score -1):

It's located in the variable `$_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE']`.

I use it in a script, along with fun stuff like `HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE`. ;-)

Ciao!

Comment: I know that, but Apache does not call PHP at all.

Comment: No, it sends back the output it has in it's own cache.

Comment: "it" being apache? I don't think apache caches things unless you have mod proxy setup.  Are you *sure* it isn't caching in the browser?  Can you reproduce this behavior using curl or wget?